# Understand public hosted zone aws route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I was playing around aws route53.
I understand that a private hosted zone will help resolve the domain name in vpc. For example i can create a google.com private hosted zone to resolve google.com to my custom ip in my vpc.

NOW,  i was expecting that route53 should not allow me to create google.com **public** hosted zone as i dont own the domain. BUT it allowed me to create it

So now i am confused, What does the public hosted zone means ? How does it work? Why it allowed me to create such a hosted zone? What mental model am i missing?

Comment: You can create that zone, but no one will come there to take a look unless anme servers for parent (.com) zone point that domain to your route53 nameservers, and only domain owner can set that. https://www.google.com/search?q=how+dns+delegation+works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand when someone enters a URL in the browser, the request goes to the root name server which uses a delegation chain to resolve the authoritative namespace server .. since your custom google.com entry is not present in the authoritative namespace server, people on the internet are not resolving to it...

But the fun thing to do is if you do
`nslookup google.com yournamespaceserver`
then google.com should resolve to your custom hosted zone IP.

Comment: Thanks .. bit more study and was able to figure out that there are 13 root ns server which delegate to TLD ns which further delegate to authorised ns (which is registered with registrar like godaddy)

Answer (score 3):

Public hosted zone means it should be available all over the internet for domain discovery. Although AWS allows you to create public hosted zone even for domain that you dont own, but this would not be mapped to root NS servers in DNS hierarchy which means **this hosted zone does not have any relevance**. Below quote from AWS:

> You can create a hosted zone only for a domain that you have
> permission to administer.
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html

Also, there is a similar discussion on reddit which is helpfull as well. Link below for reference:
https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6nx9u7/what_happens_when_i_create_a_hosted_zone_in/